# Is it safe to have an additional load before a switch first circuit?

Tags: electrical

I have a circuit going to the bathroom that is a switch first. It's only load after the switch is a simple light and bathroom fan.

Is it possible and safe to have an additional outlet before the switch that is independent of the light's on/off state?

Comment: Is this going to be for the bathroom?

Comment: It's going to be for the room next to the bathroom. The cable reaches the point where I would like to put an additional receptacle before it reaches the bathroom.

Is it not up to code if I have a "pre" load before the light circuit?

Comment: Is there a separate circuit for the bathroom receptacle(s)?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes the bathroom receptacles are on a separate circuit. Only the bathroom light and fan are on the circuit that are controlled by a switch. The outlets in the bathroom itself are separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2014 NEC, 210.11.C.3 Bathroom branch circuits. 1 20 amp shall be provided and have no other outlets. So it would be a code violation if not in the bathroom.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that the technical term is a `branch circuit` - will use that from now on for my research. Hopefully I can find another way to get the additional outlet.

Comment: @DylanPierce -- if your branch circuit isn't running the bathroom receptacles, then it doesn't fall under the 210.11(C)(3) stuff as that's for the bathroom *receptacle* small appliance branch circuit (think hairdryer)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel ohhh ok. This branch circuit would just be used for adding one receptacle that will power a small propane oven's ignition. It would be in the room adjacent to the bathroom.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel looking at figure 3 - http://ecmweb.com/nec/code-basics/101ecmCBfig3.jpg

  My extra outlet outside of the bathroom would break code. Woof. Guess I have to move a receptacle.

Comment: @DylanPierce -- that illustration doesn't refer to your case though

Answer (score 1):

### Go ahead and add it

Since this receptacle is being installed to the bathroom *general lighting* branch circuit, and not the bathroom *small appliance receptacle* branch circuit, 210.11(C)(3) and its exception *don't* apply to it as that Code section deals with bathroom *receptacle* branch circuits:

> **(3) Bathroom Branch Circuits.** In addition to the number
>   of branch circuits required by other parts of this section, at
>   least one 120-volt, 20-ampere branch circuit shall be provided to supply a bathroom receptacle outlet(s). Such circuits shall have no other outlets.
>
> *Exception: Where the 20-ampere circuit supplies a single
>   bathroom, outlets for other equipment within the same
>   bathroom shall be permitted to be supplied in accordance
>   with 210.23(A)(1) and (A)(2).*

Also, the exception doesn't come into play as the OP's bathroom receptacles don't share a branch circuit with the OP's bathroom lights.

Comment: The section of code you reference "shall be provided to supply a bathroom receptacle outlet(s). Such circuits shall have no other outlets." says no other outlets.

Comment: @EdBeal -- the circuit he's putting the new outlet on has no bathroom receptacles on it

Comment: If there are no receptacles then it could be added.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read the link below the 20-A circuit for one bathroom can have the receptacle, the lights and the fan all on the same circuit. "As long as no single load exceeds 10 A." Of course a 1600 W hairdryer exceeds 10 A, but you could provide a 1200 W hairdryer and claim that is the intended load.  Picky, picky . . .  http://ecmweb.com/code-basics/branch-circuits-part-1 See Fig. 4.

Editing But one cannot have a "non-bathroom" load (receptacle or otherwise) on the 20-A circuit for the bathroom receptacle. Apparently one can have a single 20-A circuit that powers receptacles only in two (or more?!) bathrooms . . . What the heck?

Comment: My reaction is somewhat heightened by the fact that I live in a tract home with two bathrooms built in 1970. As built, each had one receptacle, one integrated ceiling unit (exhaust fan, one incandescent flood, one heat lamp with fan blowing over it) and three porcelain lamp bases in a box over the lavatory.  The bathrooms are on **the same 15-A breaker** (new 15-A GE GFCI) and wired in 12 AWG aluminum. Presumably this was the code in Dallas in 1970, I dunno. One of the people in the house uses a hairdryer (1200 W lo / 1500 W hi) for short periods. We never have had the breaker trip.

Comment: The 10 amp limit is for fixed devices only. This is to prevent an electric heater or jacuzzi tub from using two much power and creating a problem. I was an apprentice in the 70's and AL wire was really being pushed , 12 gauge on a 15 amp would have been code. Also if there was a common wall the outlets could be on the same circuit.

Comment: In my case there is no common wall between the bathrooms. Unfortunately my panel is full. If I had a slot left, I would consider separating the two bathrooms on two different 15-A circuits.

Comment: Will your panel accept tandem breakers? If the listing states more possible breakers than slots you could add a tandem. Example 20/30 20 slots but 10 would accept tandem breakers or 20/40. These are not very expensive if the panel will accept them it will give you more circuits.

Comment: @Ed Beal my old GE panel accepts individual 1/2" wide breakers for the lower part for branch circuits. (The upper part has spaces for full-size 2-pole breakers for ele dryer, a/c condenser, ele range and a 60-A "main section", a feeder breaker for the lower part.  It has room for 16 1/2" breakers and there are 10 of these (5 are 15 A and 5 are 20 A).  There are two GFCI breakers which are 1" wide, and there is one 2-pole 50-A breaker to which the Eaton whole house surge protector is connected. I really need to put in a sub-panel.